# How can i make projects bound to eachother in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, binding

I have 3 projects in Eclipse that are bound to eachother. With bound i mean this:

- Everytime i add a class in one of the projects, the other projects also updates themselves and add the class

Now i want to add another project to these, but i don't know how to bind it together with the other projects.

Any suggestions?

### Edit:

[alt text http://img218.imageshack.us/img218/8441/eclipsesymbol2.png](http://img218.imageshack.us/img218/8441/eclipsesymbol2.png)
This is how the projects are listed in eclipse.
Any explanation about the [smax3]?
Any explanation about the ">"?

Thanks

---

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just completed my answer to illustrate your picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(See **[Java Build Path](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-properties-build-path.htm)** Eclipse Help page)

In the build path of a project, you can declare a project in the dependency list of another.

[image: Build Path]

In the tab "`Projects`", add the project "`P`" you depend on.

Each time that project "`P`" is changed, your project will take the modifications into account.

[image: Dependencies]

See that old but still accurate article [Configuring an Eclipse Java Project](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=367962)

---

[image: Projects under source control]

This illustrates two project under version control (CVS or more probably SVN with Subversive or [SubClipse](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/index.php)).

See the [label decoration help page](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/preferences/pref_label_decors.php).
Here: "`[smax3]`" is the name of name of the SVN repo, with an "Outgoing flag" (the '`>`'), meaning some resources within the project need to be committed and published to the SVN repo.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
I have added some more questions and a image. Hope you can answer them.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information.
I have looked at the projects' properties, and it does not seem that any of them have any projects in their dependency list. But i read about the "Order and Export", and all the projects have listed their folders here. This is what i read:
" If project A exports junit.jar, project B can use it at compile time". Is this something that i may look further into?

Comment: @ikky: no, in your case, I would stick with the Projects tabs, which will take into account the `.class` directories, instead of the jars.